# Netbeans Formatting from Terminal

Tags: netbeans, terminal, formatting

SITUATION: In Netbeans you can format the whole project or its folders recursively by selecting a tree node in **Project** window and pressing *Ctrl+Shift+F*.

PROBLEM: To get unified format for our team project we need to format it with fixed formatting settings before merges. Some don't use Netbeans. Opening it for this sort of operation is uncomfortable. Also imported formatting settings can be manually modified by irresponsible programmers later. Automation is required. A possibility to call this function as a part of special script is required.

QUESTION: **Is there a way to call this Netbeans function from terminal (command line)?**